# View on View controllers are all square shaped on Xcode 11, how?

Tags: swift, xcode, view, autolayout, storyboard

[image: view on view controllers are square shaped]

I have tried to change it's size manually (by dragging) and still not working.

Comment: Try tapping on "View as ..." on the bottom of the middle pane showing the storyboard, then choose a device that is not an iPad. Is your app supposed to be for iPads? If so, you should adapt your interface for them too.

Answer (score 0):

You can set its Content size to whatever you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 13 a "Modal" segue will show the presenting controller that way by default.

If you want the view controller to occupy the whole screen, set "Full Screen" on the "presentation" setting of any segue entering that controller.
[Segue Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHnln.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your view presents programmatically (not via storyBoard), have this in mind:
From XCode 11 and up, when you build for iPad you have to add "modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen" to get full screen views, not square ones. As follows:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you want transparency on the new viewController, you can write ".overFullScreen", as follows:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen 
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```